# Parameters of Functions

Tags: c++, function, parameters

Some important parameters for functions are pointers, address, and arrays.

```
void somethingHappens (int *a); //pointers
void somethingHappens (int& a); //address
void somethingHappens (int arg[]); //array
```

If I was to use(initialize) the functions above, how would it look like? \My answers are below. Correct me if I am wrong.

```
int i = 9; int j[20] = {1,2,3,4,5};
somethingHappens(&i); //pointers
somethingHappens(&i); //address - Not really sure...
somethingHappens(j); //array
```

Am I missing any other important parameters for functions?

Comment: Did you try compiling, running, and testing each?

Comment: "*//address*" That's not an address; that is a *reference*.

Comment: *"//array"* That's not an array, that is, unfortunately, due to a poor language design decision, a pointer.

Comment: arrays are internally converted to pointers. Did you read the chapter on "reference" variables and read WHY they were created? Secondly try compiling each and test. Then compile with two cases and lastly compile with all three cases.

Comment: Can you guys tell me what is correct and what is not. If possible provide the correct solution. I want to make sure that I know all the possible parameters that are not "normal".

@PrototypeStark
What chapter? Can you link me?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: from 8.3.5.5 'After
determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is
adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively.' - so clearly it _is_ valid to consider it a parameter of type "array of T", from a pre-adjustment perspective.

Comment: @TonyD: Nevermind, I misunderstood what you were arguing.

Comment: @dalawh Given that this question is fairly basic, you may benefit from reading an introduction to C++, perhaps one of the books on this list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @dalawh: Correct solution *to what*? You haven't stated a problem, so there's nothing to solve.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case (as you have rightly mentioned), the argument is passed through the pointer i.e. the address of the argument is passed to the method. Thereby, the method has direct access to the memory location *pointed by the pointer* (remember that pointer is also a variable, but it holds a memory address instead).

In the second case, the argument is passed as an alias. It is very similar to the first method, the only different is that you are **not** using the memory address of the argument to access its value.

In the third case (interestingly), when you pass the array variable, it is passed by reference (in case of an array arr[], arr represents the base address of the array i.e. address of zeroth element or &arr[0]). So manipulating the array in the method will reflect in the caller as well.

In the **second case**,

```
void somethingHappens (int& a);
```

The call to this should be of the form,

```
somethingHappens(i); 
// somethingHappens(&i); is wrong because &i means the location of i, 
// while the method is expecting an alias and not an address
```

**More information**

- [C++ References](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html)
- [What are the differences between pointer variable and reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. By any chance, are there any other parameters of a function that I should know that aren't simple?

Comment: @dalawh: you've struggled to understand the simplest parameters... I'd wait a while before worrying about how complex they can get, but when you're ready - takes most programmers a few years of full time C++ - check out template expressions....